# Can you have multiple input msmq queues to nServiceBus host?

Tags: nservicebus

Is there any way to configure an nServiceBus endpoint to receive messages from more than one queue?

I am looking into implementing an nServiceBus Saga which takes messages from multiple queues (one per message type). The point of which is to be able to monitor traffic for each message type.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Not without a lot of weird hacks.

The better approach would be to deploy your saga to multiple endpoints, each one responsible for processing the messages for the queue it sits on, but cooperating through the shared saga data.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is that you have an endpoint that handles multiple message types using one queue. You can specify the order that the messages are handled in too.